# Mule 3.3.0 JBoss Transaction Manager java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: java, jboss, transactions, esb, mule

I'm migrating from Mule version 3.1.0 to 3.3.0.

When running my code using a JBoss transaction manager:

```
<jbossts:transaction-manager>
  <property key="test" value="TEST"/>
</jbossts:transaction-manager>
```

I get the following exception:

```
2012-07-03 15:04:40,501 SEVERE [org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy] -     Caught exception in Exception Strategy: errorCode: 0; Caused by: errorCode: 0 
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:335) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.common.arjPropertyManager.getObjectStoreEnvironmentBean()Lcom/arjuna/ats/arjuna/common/ObjectStoreEnvironmentBean;
```

My classpath contains: "mule-module-jbossts-3.3.0.jar". 
If i'm using "mule-module-jbossts-3.1.0.jar" it works fine.

Is this a Mule problem?

After verifying i'm using the latest jboss tx manager (4.16.4) i'm getting the following exception:

```
2012-07-08 18:43:56,772  SEVERE [org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy] - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: errorCode: 0; Caused by: errorCode: 0
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.arjuna.ats.internal.jts.OTSImpleManager
    at com.arjuna.ats.jts.OTSManager.get_current(OTSManager.java:71)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState(BaseTransaction.java:265)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.jts.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:72)
    at org.mule.transaction.XaTransaction.doBegin(XaTransaction.java:63)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractTransaction.begin(AbstractTransaction.java:66)
    at org.mule.transaction.XaTransactionFactory.beginTransaction(XaTransactionFactory.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.transport.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:145)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:84)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:53)
```

What's wrong?
(I have jbossts.jar in my classpath)

Comment: I've just tested it and it works fine on my end. What version of jbossjta do you have in your classpath?

Comment: Mule mule-module-jbossts is built against jbossjta 4.15.0.Final, do you experience the same problem by using that version?

Comment: Just checked with 4.15.0 - seems like it works. Couldn't find on Mule's web site which jbossts version they support. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add your final solution as an answer, so that it can be upvoted and easier to find :)